# Wildcard, '%', within ColdFusion cfscript query LIKE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, coldfusion

Is it possible to use a wildcard in a SQL LIKE statement within a ColdFusion cfscript query?

An example that doesn't work:

```
local.q = new Query(); 
local.q.setDatasource(variables.dsn);
local.q.addParam(name='lastname', value='%' & arguments.lastname,     cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");
local.qString = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE lastname LIKE :lastname';
local.q.setSQL(local.qString);
local.result = local.q.execute().getResult();
```

I also tried these, which didn't work:

```
local.qString = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE lastname LIKE %:lastname';
local.qString = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE lastname LIKE '%:lastname'";
```

**UPDATE:**

I am using MS SQL Server 2008.

The query works fine within SQL Server Mgmt Studio... I think it has something to do with how to format the query within cfscript tags?

Comment: is it possible that your DBMS does not support doing `LIKE` with `%` as first char?

Comment: This works fine in MS SQL.  I'd tend to think along the lines of Henry that this is not supported.

Comment: "Didn't work" is vague.  What does it mean?  Did you get an error?  Did you not get your expected results?  If you didn't get your expected results did you try it outside of ColdFusion to help isolate the problem?

Comment: in MSSQL using tags `<cfqueryparam value="%#arguments.lastname#">` is the correct syntax. Looks like what you're trying to do, so your dbms probably does not support this

Comment: Small aside, since many things are database specific, *always* include database type and version with `sql` questions. You will get faster, more accurate, answers when people do not have to guess which flavor you are using :)

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse .. but you need to explain what you mean by "doesn't work" and "works fine". As others mentioned, the code above runs without error in SQL Server and successfully returns all records **ending with** the supplied argument. What result are *you* getting - and what result did you expect instead?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You're setting it in the param, which is correct. I'm not sure why it's not working with you.

I did the following and it worked.

```
var qryArgsCol = {};            
qryArgsCol.datasource = variables.datasource;
qryArgsCol.SQL = "                      
                SELECT ID
                FROM Users
                WHERE LastName LIKE :searchStringParam
                ";
var qryGetID = new query(argumentCollection=qryArgsCol);
qryGetID.addParam(name="searchStringParam", value="%" & searchString, cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");
qryGetIDResult = qryGetID.execute().getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the dbms used, that single and double quotes may be interpreted when the sql statement is run. What dbms are you using? Your statement now doesn't select for the value in the variable, but for any user whose lastname is "lastname". It should be something like:

```
  lastname like '%#lastname#'
```

Comment: Actually that is what their CF code is doing already. They are just adding the value `%#arguments.lastName#` via a parameter (ie bind variable).

Answer (score 0):

There's a response here from Adam Cameron, which was apparently deleted by an overzealous mod.

Rather than repeat what he says, I've just copied and pasted (with emphasis added to the key parts):

---

Just to clarify that **the syntax you tried in your first example *does* work**. That is the correct approach here.  To clarify / explain:

The `<cfquery>` version of the example you have would be along the lines of:

```
<cfqueryparam value="%foo">
```

So in the function version, the param would be `?` or `:paramName` and the value of the param would continue to be `"%foo"`.

The `%` is part of the param value, not the SQL string.

So given that "doesn't work" for you, **it would help if you posted the error, or whatever it is that causes you to think it's not working** (what your expectation is, and what the actual results are). Then we can deal with the actual cause of your problem, which is not what you think it is, I think.

Does the query work fine as a `<cfquery>`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `CFQuery` tag instead of attempting to run queries within `CFScript`.  Unless you REALLY know what you are doing.  I say this because the `CFQuery` tag has some built-in functionality that not only makes building queries easier for you but may also protect you from unforeseen attacks (the SQL injection type).  For example, when using `CFQuery` it will automatically escape single-quotes for you so that inserting things like `'well isn't that a mess'` will not blow up on you.  You also have the benefit of being able to use the `CFQueryParam` tag to further battle against SQL injection attacks.  While you may be able to use the `CFQueryParam` functionality within `CFScript` it is not as straight forward (at least not for me).

[See this blog post from Ben Nadel talking about some of this.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1680-Learning-ColdFusion-9-Using-CFQuery-In-CFScript-Can-Enable-SQL-Injection-Attacks.htm)

So in `CFQuery` tags your query would look something like this:

```
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
    SELECT name
    FROM users
    WHERE lastname LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%:#arguments.lastname#" maxlength="256" />
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I had to remove outer single quotes and omit the colon, like `LIKE <cfqueryPARAM value = '#Form.Model_srch#%' CFSQLType = 'CF_SQL_VARCHAR'>`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The outer quotes are not needed for this example. I will remove them from my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that you ultimately need to see what CF gives the DB server. In this instance, you can try this mockup to get close and find the same error in SSMS by messing with the quotes/value in the param declaration:

```
 declare @param1 varchar(max) = '%Eisenlohr';

 SELECT name FROM users WHERE lastname LIKE @param1
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem as the original poster where it "wasn't working" and I didn't get any results from the query of queries.
The problem for me is that the wildcard search is case-sensitive.

```
 local.q = new Query();  
 local.q.setDatasource(variables.dsn);
 local.q.addParam(name='lastname', value='%' & LCase(arguments.lastname), cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"); 
 local.qString = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE LOWER(lastname) LIKE :lastname'; 
 local.q.setSQL(local.qString); 
 local.result = local.q.execute().getResult();
```

So what I did was made sure the incoming argument was lower case and made sure the comparing field in the SQL was lower case as well and it worked.

Comment: Yep. QoQ are always case sensitive: [From documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7fd4): *"Unlike the rest of ColdFusion, Query of Queries is case-sensitive..."*.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
     local.q = new Query(); 
        local.q.setDatasource(variables.dsn);

        local.q.addParam(name="lastname", cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar",value='%ARGUMENTS.lastname' );
        local.qString = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE lastname LIKE :lastname';
        local.q.setSQL(local.qString);
        local.result = local.q.execute().getResult();
```