# cfscript and queryExecute() using like instead of equals

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I'm curious if this is the correct method to use the like operator when using queryExecute() in a cfscript function.

```
if( len(arguments?.lastName) ){
    local.sqlWhere & = " AND t_lastname LIKE :lName";
    local.sqlParams.lName = { value : arguments.lastName & '%', cfsqltype:'cf_sql_varchar'};
};
```

Is it just appended like a string with & '%'?

Comment: Yes. The wildcard must be part of the *value*. The fact that it's inside a structure makes no difference. Ultimately it's just concatenating a variable and string literal. So the results are the same.  Possible duplicate of [Wildcard, '%', within ColdFusion cfscript query LIKE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269948/wildcard-within-coldfusion-cfscript-query-like-statement)

Answer (score 0):

I've just go through your issue. In coldfusion & symbol always concatenation the two string. So we could not able to use like that. Here I've wrote some sample code for you please check that. I hope it will more help full to wrote a script based query.

```
local.MyQry = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 1=1 ";
```

I've used same condition from you. Not sure about your conditions

```
if( len(arguments?.lastName) ){

    local.MyQry &= " AND Email like :email"
}
```

Here concatenate the query with previous one if the condition is true. And mentioned :(colon as we are going to use as queryparam)

```
local.qry = new Query( datasource = 'your DB name' , sql = Local.MyQry);

if( len(arguments?.lastName) ){
     local.qry.addParam( name="email", value="%#Arguments.email#%", cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");

}
return local.qry.execute();
```

You can give the `%` symbol here based on your scenario . Ex `%#Arguments.email#`. or `%#Arguments.email#%`

I hope this will help you more. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Interestingly enough, on CF2016, my sample code works as expected too, so either way will work.